# Mapbox-gl-js `getClusterLeaves` returns features in its callback that cannot be passed to `setFeatureState`

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

What I am trying to achieve is to set the state of cluster leaves upon clicking on the cluster.
When clicking on the cluster, I am getting its leaves with the code below.

```
map.getClusterLeaves(clusterId, pointCount, 0, (error, leaves) => { // callback function }
```

And inside the callback function, I am trying to set the state of the leaves like below:

```
map.getClusterLeaves(clusterId, pointCount, 0, (error, leaves) => {
  if (error) return;

  leaves.forEach((leave) => {
    map.setFeatureState(leave, {
      selected: true,
    });
  });
});
```

This throws error as the leave (feature) returned from the callback of the `getClusterLeaves` doesn't have the `id` field.

For `queryRenderedFeatures` which returns an array of features, it returns the full set of feature with `id` field, thus I can pass them to `setFeatureState`.

```
map.queryRenderedFetures(bbox, { layers: ['layerId'] }, (_, features) => {
  features.forEach((feature) => {
    map.setFeatureState(feature, { selected: true });
  });
});
```

In the [mapbox-gl documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource%23getclusterleaves), it just states the features are retrieved in the callback function. There is no mention about why they don't have the full properties of the feature.

How can I get the full properties of the features retrieved from the `getClusterLeaves`?

*** Edit ***

Same thing happens on the `getClusterChildren`

```
map.getClusterChildren(clusterId, (_, children) => {
  for (const child of children) {
    map.setFeatureState(child, { selected: true });
  }
});
```

The error message that I am getting is as below:

```
The source 'undefined' does not exist in the map's style.
```

Initially I thought it's because the retrieved features in the callback doesn't have the `id` field, but seems like it's something else.

*** Another update ***

Turns out, previous error message is because the returned features doesn't have `source` property. Manually providing the source id resolves the issue.

```
map.queryRenderedFetures(bbox, { layers: ['layerId'] }, (_, features) => {
  features.forEach((feature) => {
    map.setFeatureState({ ...feature, source: 'sourceId' }, { selected: true });
  });
});
```

And for the `getClusterChildren`:

```
map.getClusterChildren(clusterId, (_, children) => {
  for (const child of children) {
    map.setFeatureState({ ...child, source: 'sourceId' }, { selected: true });
  }
});
```

Now I am getting a new error message:

```
Error: The feature id parameter must be provided.
```

This is truly because feature retrieved in the callback doesn't have the `id` property.